# CCavenue payment gateway integration in ios apps

Tags: payment

How to register My IOS App in ccavenue payment gateway??

CCAvenue doesn't have any readymade plugin for ios apps.So how to register in it to get unique merchant_id??

Comment: Please refer my answer on this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23777006/ccavenue-gateway-integration-kit-for-ios-application/32863204#32863204