# "Undefined symbol: _RSA_public_encrypt" issue in CCAvenue Payment gateway in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, openssl, ccavenue

I need to integrate "CCAvenue Payment gateway" in my project, I followed here Sager Sukode  [this answer with All 8steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23777006/ccavenue-gateway-integration-kit-for-ios-application)

**I have added like this in project**

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Before running the project there was no issues once i run the project then why i got these 4 issues after adding the above** please guide me i really didn't understand the reason for above issues, how to fix these issues. please help me. first time I am working on this payment gateway, got stuck from long

[image]